Is there any significance to great northern beans being wrinkled before soaking?
To make a long story short most articles I read about this talk about wrinkled beans after soaking not before soaking.
I also had an issue cooking them and tossed them out but that could have been a one-off or a red herring. Mostly I am interested in knowing what wrinkles in beans mean. The package date was not expired but I could not soften after a reasonable time cooking.

While there are a few beans that have a wrinkly appearance when dried (such as some varieties of giant beans), great northern aren't one of those.  The only reason I can think of that they would have wrinkly skins when still in the bag is that they got wet, and then dried again in the bag.
In which case: yeah, throw them out.

Thank you that was very helpful. They were a little yellow too. I told what happened to the company that sold them to me and asked if anyone else had problems with that lot number on the package and they said not that they could find. I let it slide but I did want them to at least know what happened.

If the bag isn't airtight, then exposure to water could have been the fault of anyone who handled them in between them packing the beans and you buying them. Or, for that matter, you.
